# unexpected result for a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to filter a populated element depending if it's `true || false`, then I remove (or don't) some fields.

That said, I'm literally copying the code of my endpoint with the unexpected response:

```
router.get('/endpoint', tokenAuth, function (req, res) {
  var json_allData;
  Model.getInfo(req.query.info)
    .then(function (data) {
      json_allData = data;
      return Model.filterAnonymous(data.subdocument);
    })
    .then(function (data) { // << Data here is a subdocument filtered as expected
      res.status(200).json({ data: json_allData }); // << WTF??? data has been filtered in the json_allData but I'm not doing anything!
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      res.status(400).json({ msg: error });
    });
});
```

Hope someone can throw some light here.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: You're probably mutating the array.

Comment: `json_allData = data;` Sharing the reference happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
json_allData = data;
```

You make `json_allData` point to the same memory as `data`. This means both variables reference the same object.

Now when you do

```
Model.filterAnonymous(data.subdocument);
```

That changes the `subdocument` property which is part of the object `data` is referencing and that is **still the same object** `json_allData` is referencing.